# ¿Cómo conectar dos bases de datos de un mismo cluster de mongo a un mismo backend en NodeJs?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, cluster

Estoy creando un backend en NodeJS, estoy utilizando un clúster en MongoDB Atlas donde guardo la información. En este clúster tengo dos bases de datos distintas, PRE y PRO.

En ambas bases de datos se guardan documentos que comparten un mismo Schema, es decir, la información que contienen sigue un mismo formato pero es distinta la info en sí.

El problema es que no se como realizar dos conexiones de bases de datos distintas, y sobre todo, como reenviar la información que recojo a una u otra.

Esta sería la estructura de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo db.js realizo la conexión (todo okai, tanto si me conecto a la bd A como a la B el problema está con ambas a la vez).

Aquí os dejo mi archivo de conexión a la bd:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://' + process.env.DB_USER + ':' + process.env.DB_PASS + '@xxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/' + process.env.DB + '?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

En la carpeta PRE y PRO guardo la información con el comando .save() propio de mongoose. El problema es que no se como redirigir la información a una BD u otra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida =)

Comment: Claro que se puede, en cuanto pueda te doy una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, creo que mi fallo es en como estoy declarando y llamando la conexión con Mongo ¿es así? 

Cuando puedas me iluminas =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea acceder a 2 bases de datos diferentes de MongoDB, usando el mismo modelo de datos creado mediante un [Schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) de [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/).

Se desea usar dinámicamente la Base de Datos `PRE` o la base de datos `PRO` según la solicitud realizada sea para una u otra base de datos. También cabe la posibilidad de realizar la misma operación en ambas bases de datos.

La solución no es trivial. Resulta que los [Modelos](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) de Mongoose están atados a una conexión por defecto, es decir, a una Base de Datos por defecto (en este punto una conexión de Mongoose se refiere efectivamente a una Base de Datos).

Cuando ejecutamos la sentencia:

```js
mongoose.connect(uri, options)
```

En la variable `uri` se determina la base de datos a la cual Mongoose se conecta, actualmente tu tienes este valor como:

```js
let uri = 'mongodb+srv://' + process.env.DB_USER + ':' + process.env.DB_PASS + '@xxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/' + process.env.DB + '?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
```

siendo el nombre de tu Base de Datos el que se toma de la variable de entorno `process.env.DB`.

Toda acción realizada sobre modelos que usen esta conexión será realizada sobre dicha base de datos. Para  usar otra base de datos, necesitas otra conexión. Pero no sería lógico tener dos llamadas al método `connect()` de Mongoose.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero es entender que un modelo debe atarse a una conexión (Base de Datos), pero si llamamos al método `model()` de Mongoose, se creará el modelo atado a la conexión por defecto de Mongoose, cosa que queremos evitar.

Entonces, debemos crear el modelo de acuerdo a la Base de Datos y no como un Modelo de datos por defecto.

Suponiendo que tienes el siguiente Esquema:

```js
const AppSchema = new Schema({
  // ...
});

// vamos a exportar el Esquema y no el Modelo.

module.exports = AppSchema;
```

Ahora, para crear un modelo atado a la Base de Datos de nuestra elección debemos importar este esquema y crear el modelo a partir del mismo.

Sin embargo, para poder hacerlo, ya debemos tener una instancia de nuestra conexión hacia el servidor: *la conexión por defecto*. No importa a qué base de datos apunte la misma, no la usaremos, incluso puede apuntar a ninguna base de datos:

```js
let uri = 'mongodb+srv://' + process.env.DB_USER + ':' + process.env.DB_PASS + '@xxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(uri, oprtions);
```

Una vez tenemos la conexión por defecto, podemos crear una nueva conexión (apuntar a una Base de Datos) usando el método [`createConnection`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-createConnection) como se ve a continuación:

```js
let conn = mongoose.createConnection(uri, options);
```

En este caso el parámetro `uri` es igual que el que pasamos a la conexión por defecto, y es en este momento que indicamos el nombre de la base de datos a utilizar.

Otra forma en la que podemos crear una conexión a una base de datos diferente en el mismo Servidor es con el método [`useDb()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-useDb) que recibe como parámetro el nombre de la base de datos que deseamos utilizar.

```js
let conn = mongoose.connection.useDb(dbName);
```

Dependiendo de lo que estés tratando de implementar, podrías usar un método u otro.

La diferencia radica en que el `useDb()` usará el mismo *pool* de conexión para hacer el cambio de base de datos. Esto es muy distinto a `createConnection()` que crea un nuevo *pool* de conexión.

Ahora, para usar el modelo de datos, el mismo debe crearse a partir del esquema que hemos exportado previamente y sobre la conexión (Base de Datos) en la que deseamos trabajar.

Supongamos que tenemos la siguiente función en Express:

```js
// manejador para la ruta: POST /document?db=<valor>
const saveDocument = async (req, res) => {
  const dbName = req.query.db || process.env.DB || 'PRE'; // <- Base de datos PRE por defecto
  const uri = 'mongodb+srv://' + process.env.DB_USER + ':' + process.env.DB_PASS + '@xxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/' + dbName + '?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
  const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  };
  let conn = mongoose.createConnection(uri, options);
  // Ahora procedemos a crear el modelo de datos:
  let AppModel = conn.model('App', AppSchema);
  let newApp = new AppModel(req.body);
  try {
    let savedApp = await newApp.save();
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'New App created',
      app: savedApp,
      db: dbName
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    // manejamos el error
    console.error(e.message);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Error',
      error: e.message
    });
  }
}
```

En la ruta en este caso, estamos indicando la base de datos sobre la cual queremos hacer la inserción. Esto es una de las muchas formas de hacerlo. Podrías enviar el nombre como el valor de un campo de un formulario, o tal vez te interese salvar en ambas bases de datos el mismo documento.

Si el caso es que en una misma petición deseas cargar el mismo documento para ambas bases de datos, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
// manejador para la ruta: POST /document
const saveDocument = async (req, res) => {
  const dbPRE = 'PRE'; // <- Base de datos PRE
  const dbPRO = 'PRO'; // <- Base de datos PRO
  // Primero creamos una conexión con PRE
  const uri = 'mongodb+srv://' + process.env.DB_USER + ':' + process.env.DB_PASS + '@xxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/' + dbPRE + '?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
  const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  };
  let conn = mongoose.createConnection(uri, options);
  // Ahora procedemos a crear el modelo de datos:
  let AppModelPRE = conn.model('App', AppSchema);
  let newAppPRE = new AppModelPRE(req.body);
  try {
    // salvamos en la base de datos PRE
    let savedAppPRE = await newAppPRE.save();

    // cambiamos ahora a la base de datos PRO (usando el mismo pool de conexión anterior)
    conn.useDb(dbPRO);
    // creamos el modelo para la nueva DB
    let AppModelPRO = conn.model('App', AppSchema);
    let newAppPRO = new AppModelPRO(req.body);

    // salvamos en la base de datos PRO
    let savedAppPRO = await newAppPRO.save();
    
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'New Apps created',
      appPRE: savedAppPRE,
      appPRO: savedAppPRO
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    // manejamos el error
    console.error(e.message);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Error',
      error: e.message
    });
  }
}
```

Esto parece mucho código para realizar ambas operaciones, por lo que se debería implementar algún tipo de patrón para solventar la situación de escribir tanto código de forma repetitiva. Usualmente se usa el patrón de diseño [*Factory Method*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)).

Una forma en la que podrías automatizar la carga de modelos y la llamada de los mismos es creando una función para crear conexiones y una función para crear modelos.

Por ejemplo:

**Factoría de conexiones:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const DB_USER = process.env.DB_USER || 'defaultUser';
const DB_PASS = process.env.DB_PASS || 'defaultPass';

const options: ConnectOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  autoIndex: true,
  poolSize: 15,
  bufferMaxEntries: 0,
  connectTimeoutMS: 15000,
  socketTimeoutMS: 30000
};

const crearConexion = (dbName) => {
  const uri = `mongodb+srv://${DB_USER}:${DB_PASS}@xxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/${dbName}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
  return mongoose.createConnection(uri, options);
}

const obtenerConexion = (dbName) => {
  let [ conexion ] = mongoose.connections.filter(conn => conn.name === dbName);
  if(!conexion) {
    conexion = crearConexion(dbName);
  }
  return conexion;
}

module.exports = obtenerConexion;
```

Con esto tenemos una forma de obtener una conexión existente en el *pool* de conexiones de Mongoose o crearla si la misma no existe.

Para crear los modelos podemos hacer lo siguiente:

**Factoría de Modelos:**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const crearModelo = (nombre, schema, conexion) => {
  const modelo = conexion.model(nombre, schema);
  return modelo;
}

const obtenerModelo = (nombre, schema, conexion) => {
  let model;
  if(conexion.modelNames().includes(nombre);
    model = conexion.model(nombre);
  }
  else {
    model = crearModelo(nombre, schema, conexion);
  }
  return model;
}

module.exports = obtenerModelo;
```

En esta función recibimos el nombre del modelo, el esquema de datos y la conexión a la que va a pertenecer nuestro modelo como parámetros.

El método `obtenerModelo` primero verifica si el modelo ya existe en la lista de modelos de la colección antes de proceder a crearlo. Esto evita la sobre escritura del modelo de datos (no sería necesario crear un modelo para la conexión si el mismo ya existe).

Para usar ambos métodos podrías hacer algo como:

```js
const AppSchema = require('./path/to/AppSchema');
const obtenerConexion = require('./path/to/FactoriaConexion');
const obtenerModelo = require('./path/to/FactoriaModelo');

const salvarApp = async (req, res) => {
  let connPRE = obtenerConexion('PRE');
  let AppPRE = obtenerModelo('AppPRE', AppSchema, connPRE);
  let newAppPRE = new AppPRE(req.body);
  try {
    let savedAppPRE = newAppPRE.save();
    return res.status(201).json({ message: 'Success'});
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e.message);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error'});
  }
}

module.exports = salvarApp;
```

El código se ve mucho más limpio y ordenado y la función hace lo que debe hacer sin distraerse en crear conexiones o modelos o cosas que ensucian el código.
Existen muchas otras formas de lograr el objetivo, pero todas apuntan a lo mismo como clave: *se crea el modelo dinámicamente, de acuerdo a la conexión (Base de Datos a la que apunta)*.

Este tipo de patrón de trabajo sobre múltiples bases de datos con el mismo esquema se conoce como [*Sistema de Tenencia Mútliple*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenencia_m%C3%BAltiple) (*Multi Tenant*).

Puedes leer más información sobre conexiones múltiples a MongoDB con Mongoose en la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections).

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Sos un crack Mauricio, no solo me funcionó, sino que entendí perfectamente todo el funcionamiento del proceso, respuesta perfecta +100